# WSDL2Java won't install in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, wsdl2java

Hee guys,

I've been searching for over an hour now to find a solution to this. And now I'm writing this question.

I'm currently trying to install  the plugin voor WSDL2Java so i can continue on my project that requires webserver with WSDL. I've downloaded the following 2 from: https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/tools/index.html

- Service Archive Wizard - Eclipse Plug-in
- Code Generator Wizard - Eclipse Plug-in

However after putting the content in the dropins folder OR plugin folder and rebooting my eclipse, it won't show anyting im supposed to see.

Anyone knows why eclipse isn't installing this plugins?

Comment: Have you followed the installation instructions here https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/tools/eclipse/plugin-installation.html. Are you using the correct version of Eclipse?

Comment: Yes and yes, I've tried snapshots and alot of other stuf. I got the latest eclipse version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working after installing WTP plugin it automaticly added the WSDL2Java plugins.